# Ruby on rails : using same instance variable on new and edit form on index page with partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, simple-form

On my index page, I display a list of "tasks"

I have a button at the top to "Add a task" with a modal in partial using simple form. This works fine.

On my list of tasks, I display for every tasks an edit and delete link. Delete works fine but edit doesn't really work as it uses @task = Task.new that I set up in my controller. So the "edit" modal is in fact a "new" modal

Ideally, I would like @task to be equal to "task" in my each iterator

I have been trying many different methods to work around this problem, mainly using params :

my edit link is :

```
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      ...
      <%= link_to 'Edit', "?task_id=#{task.id}", { 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal' } %>
    <% end %>
```

In my controller, my index method looks like :

```
    if params.has_key?(:task_id)
      @task = Task.find(params[:task_id].to_i)
    else
      @task = Task.new
    end
```

However this doesn't work either and @task seems to be set up once and for all, it never goes into the condition on params.

Could this work? What is the best practice in rails for this kind of problem?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: could you post your complete controller and view? I think it may hep to better understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the task_id as a data parameter

view

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', "", { 'data-task-id' => task.id, 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal' } %>
```

controller

```
if params.has_key?(:data-task-id)
```